# Is Entity Framework considered "Best Practices" by Microsoft for data access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

We have built an ASP.NET MVC Web API web app that makes use of the Entity Framework v6.1 for data access. Recently a new Database Architect has started with the company and stated that we should be moving to stored procedures for ALL database access.

Though stored procedures can certainly be used with Entity Framework it seems to me a lot of the benefits that EF brings to the table would be negated by forcing ALL data access through stored procedures. That said, I could be wrong and want to be able to make an informed decision.

What is Microsoft's view on data access and Best Practices? Should Entity Framework be used in large scale, data-centric web apps? If using Entity Framework, should all data access be done via a stored procedure?

Comment: EF is a tool, as are stored procedures. Tools are made to help with certain jobs. Your enterprise application can, and should, safely make use of both of these tools depending on your need.

Answer (score 2):

Whilst I would argue there is no right answer to this question, it's possible to way up your options. The benefits of using sprocs are many-fold & well known. In the days before we had powerful ORM frameworks, sprocs were our best option. Writing your own data access code, usually using sprocs will & does generally beat every ORM tool every time. But it takes time to write & maintain which is where ORM tools shine.

Now you've already written your data access layer using EF. Do you have reason to believe there's a problem with it? If you do, then consider sprocs. You need to way up the pro's & con's to you on a case-by-case basis.

Sweeping generalisations very rarely work.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We do have a couple of outrageous LINQ queries where stored procs would be a good idea. However, to say ALL data access has to go through stored procedures seems like overkill to me and would eliminate some of the benifits that EF brings, but that is why I asked in case it is not

Comment: I generally go for SPs for all C/U/D operations for consistency (always update "last updated" and "last updated by" for example), and USUALLY for select based on indexes/foreign keys